# Windows App Certification Kit hangs at Modify local Windows Error Reporting settings

Tags: windows, delphi, app-certification-kit

I am working on getting my Windows desktop app certified as a first step in avoiding Smartscreen filter popping up on Win 8+

It's a standalone native code executable written in Delphi 10 Seattle.
Testing the program in Windows App Certification Kit v10.0.14393.33 hangs during the "Gathering information..." stage at: 
Process install trace files 
   In progress...
Modify local Windows Error Reporting settings
   In progress...

The app has been launched and is visible.

At first I thought this might be because the Cert Kit might be expecting a setup program ("Apps must support a clean, reversible installation”) so I built an installer using Inno Setup.

Testing the setup exe yields a hang at exactly the same point.  The setup program is running and waiting at the point where an installation folder must be entered.

I'm not supposed to run the setup, correct?  The Cert Kit program is telling me NOT to interact with the app or system.  The Cert Kit is using 0% CPU

Has anyone got a clue what might be cause the Cert kit to hang?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Per known issue causing Cert Kit to hang at the "Process Install Trace Files" task [link] (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/app-certification-kit), I actually interacted with the installer and completed the installation.  I took the option to launch my app.
Still hung at the same point after two hours :(

Comment: Fixed.  Install must be silent.